# How to pass parameters into an HTML email template from C# Windows application to Send an email

Tags: c#, html, email, windows

Hi I need to send an email using template in c# windows application . I had created a template but i am unable to pass the parameters through the html template. Here is the template which i am using.

For this HTML Template i am calling this in my windows application and sending through gmail smtp. I am able to send the mail but unable to pass the parameters into it. Please Help me out.Here is the code where i am calling in my windows application

```
try
{
  using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("H:\\Visitor Management_Project\\Visitor Management_Project\\Visitor Management_Project\\EmailTemplate.htm"))
  {
     SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("173.194.67.108", 587);
     SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
     SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
     SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("ambarishkesavarapu@gmail.com", "*******");
     //SmtpServer.Port = 587;
     SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
     SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
     message = new MailMessage();
     message.Subject = "Visitor Arrived";
     //message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
     message.IsBodyHtml = true;
     message.Body = "EmailTemplate.htm";
     //message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
     message.From = new MailAddress("ambarishkesavarapu@gmail.com");
     message.To.Add(lblCPEmail.Text);
     message.Priority = MailPriority.High;
     message.Body = reader.ReadToEnd();
     message.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
     SmtpServer.Send(message);
   }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
 }
```

How to add Parameters into HTML Template where i am getting all the parameters of that in the same page in Textboxes. Please help me out

Comment: What does your template look like? Or are you asking what the best format for templates is too?

Comment: When you bedug, what does message.Body get set to?  Does the text get read out of the file at all?

Comment: In re-reading your question...it seems you are looking to find out the best way to inject your values from controls (textboxes, etc) in your windows form into templated locations in the template html body?  Am I correct?  If so, can you supply the template file. Normally I would do this with some for of regular expression replacement but it depends on the format of your template.

Answer (score 0):

I think you already discovered the answer yourself, but I will keep posting the answer instead.

In case you are using Windows Forms and not Windows Presentation Forms (The different only the design part and many new features that does not have on Windows Forms), what I have done is like this (to send email):

```
public void SendEmail(string _from, string _fromDisplayName, string _to, string _toDisplayName, string _subject, string _body, string _password)
    {
        try
        {
            SmtpClient _smtp = new SmtpClient();

            MailMessage _message = new MailMessage();

            _message.From = new MailAddress(_from, _fromDisplayName); // Your email address and your full name

            _message.To.Add(new MailAddress(_to, _toDisplayName)); // The recipient email address and the recipient full name // Cannot be edited

            _message.Subject = _subject; // The subject of the email
            _message.Body = _body; // The body of the email

            _smtp.Port = 587; // Google mail port
            _smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // Google mail address
            _smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            _smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            _smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_from, _password); // Login the gmail using your email address and password

            _smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            _smtp.Send(_message);

            ShowMessageBox("Your message has been successfully sent.", "Success", 2);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ShowMessageBox("Message : " + ex.Message + "\n\nEither your e-mail or password incorrect. (Are you using Gmail account?)", "Error", 1);
        }
    }
```

And I am using it like this:

```
SendEmail(textBox2.Text, textBox5.Text, textBox3.Text, "YOUR_FULL_NAME", textBox4.Text, textBox6.Text, "YOUR_EMAIL_PASSWORD");
```

Here is the image:

[image]

May this answer would help you.

Cheers!